# How to include .net framework 3.5 in the installer that will be used offline

Tags: .net, installshield, offline, prerequisites, redistributable

I am using Installshield 2018 and I need to include .net framework 3.5 in my installer. What I have done so far is this:

-In the Redistributables I have checked the "Microsoft .Net Framework 3.5 SP1"

-In the right click -> properties, I have selected the Build Location: "Extract from Setup.exe"

-In the right click -> Edit Prerequisite I have included an extra condition to install it on "Windows 10 (Any)

Whenever I run the installer, the following pop up appears prompting me to download the net35.

[Installer popup prompting to download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBP67.png)

My issue is that this installer will be used on machines that have no connection to the internet, therefore downloading the .net35 will be impossible.

Is it possible to include the needed files for the installer, so that .net can be installed offline?

Comment: That is the correct and required outcome, Win10 uses a customized version of .NET, tweaked to operate correctly on Win10.  Its setup is part of the normal Win10 configuration and integrated with Windows setup, the owner must commission it before taking it offline.  Favor targeting .NET 4+ so this isn't necessary at all.

Comment: I see.. So if I understand you correctly, it is NOT possible to make the installer install the .net35 with no internet access?

Answer (score -1):

You should also set

[*Release*] Pane >> [*Setup.exe*] Tab

Set [*InstallShield Prerequisites Location*] to "*Extract From Setup.exe*" or "*Follow Invidual Selections*"